How Does Refresh Token Functionality Work in php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth?
I wonder how refresh work in https://packagist.org/packages/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth. What I know about JWT is that when a user logs in, the system should give them an access token and a refresh token.
For example, if the access token's lifetime is 5 minutes and the refresh token's lifetime is one day, then when the access token expires, the frontend automatically sends a request to the refresh link with the refresh token as a parameter. The backend checks the refresh token, and if it's valid and not expired, it updates the access token.
protected function respondWithToken($token){
        return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
    ]);
}

Then, when sending a request to refresh, it updates it like this:
public function refresh()
{
    return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
}

So, I wonder how it checks if it's the correct user. Why is there no refresh token? How does it work? Also, I need to add claims like permissions and roles to the JWT payload. Can I do it with this package?

"I wonder how it checks if it's the correct user" - correct in terms of?

@NicoHaase I mean to check if this refresh token really this users's refresh token and if it not expired ? if expired he need relogin to create new access and refresh tokens. Or I not understanding correct how it should work ? So if here not user token how system checks ? what if hacker trying to get new access token ?

It is the provider's job to ensure that all of their tokens are "unique enough" to avoid any realistic chance of collision. Possession of the token is proof that it is the user's token. (Some providers might enforce additional tests such as IP address, but I'm simplifying.) As to determining if a refresh token should be used, see this, but the general idea is to keep track of if a token is getting close to expiring, and to also try refreshing if you get an authorization exception.

@ChrisHaas, so the point is to refresh the access token when it is close to expiring, not after it expires? I thought that the token would be refreshed after it expires. Do I need to track the expiration time myself and update it? What if someone steals my token? Wouldn't they just be able to update the token and keep using it? In the case of using a refresh token, they would need both the access token and the refresh token to continue.

An access token is (usually) valid from time A to time B, so between those two times you can use it. Token expiration is recommended but not required. If provided, whether to exchange the refresh token before or after the expiration doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things. Similarly, whether you actively exchange it or passively wait for an exception before doing so also doesn't really matter. If an access token can expire, hopefully the endpoint includes the expires_in property so you can track it, at least for debugging purposes.

Whether this specific library does this for you automatically, I don't know that, however I do know that they have a refresh() method that you can invoke if required. As to "what if someone steals the access and/or refresh token" - yep, the bad guy wins! That's why these tokens really need to be guarded, and some providers might impose additional security restraints to guard against that. Also, I don't remember if the spec demands it, but tokens should only ever be transported over HTTPS.

"to check if this refresh token really this users's refresh token" - what do you mean by "this users"? Do you use any additional information to determine which user is using the token?
